# ios7 tableView is not corrently positioned with top layout guide

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm making `UIViewController` with `UITableView` on it. I would like this tableview to act like "Notes" default app (when you scroll table content is blurred under nav bar).

As far as I understand I must put my tableView BELOW `Top Layout Guide`. If I do it, content don't go under nav bar (because top layout guide is below nav bar).

If I put tableView above `Top Layout Guide` content "blurred" under nav bar and first table is hidden, and on iOs6 is upper part of tableview is hidden.

Should I manually set content offset based on iOS version? I can't use `self.topLayoutGuide` inside viewController as it was introduced only in iOs7.

**View hierarchy**

```
UINavigationController -> UiViewController
                           \
                            - UIView
                               \
                                - UITableView
```

Everything is built in storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Since you are targeting more than OS version, then I think you should handle your UI depending on the OS version.

So, yes, I do recommend setting `self.topLayoutGuide` within your code depending on the OS version.